# Regex for matching items from firewall syslog

Tags: regex

I am trying to come up with a regex to extract certain pieces of information from the below log. I've been messing with regex groups for awhile and am not getting anywhere. I would like to get the date/timestamp, the usr field, dstname field, and arg field. How can I accomplish this?

```
May  1 08:21:02 192.168.1.1 id=firewall sn=fakeserial time="2020-05-01 12:21:02 UTC" fw=1.2.3.4 pri=3 c=4 m=14 msg="Web site access denied" app=2515 sess="Auto" n=398533 usr="sampledomain\username" src=192.168.1.150:50334:X0 dst=72.21.81.240:80:X1 srcMac=b0:00:b4:18:4a:b5 dstMac=c0:ea:e4:9d:a0:8c proto=tcp/http dstname=ctldl.windowsupdate.com arg=/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/disallowedcertstl.cab code=99 Category="Administrative Custom List settings" fw_action="drop"
```

Comment: "*I've been messing with regex groups for awhile*" - please show your latest attempt, add it to the question to see where you are heading.

Comment: And also, give us an example of the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You could base it on something like this

```
(\w{3}  \d* [\d:]*).*usr="([a-z\\]*)".*dstname=([\w.]*).*arg=([\/][^ ]*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/VUIBAm/1

Comment: That's great! What about a regex to match an arg like this? the \w won't work for that but I can't do .* because it matchs the entire rest of the log.  arg=/gen_204?atyp=i&zx=1588539000507&ogsr=1&ei=dy6vXv6PNbGRggefsqLQBg&ct=7&cad=i&id=19014990&loc=imghp&prid=2&ogd=com

Comment: @user2241751 good to hear. I've updated my answer to include what you're after.